# Parcelable: Class not found when unmarshalling when calling from different App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

I am trying to pass in a bundle from App1 with some data which its data class is Auxiliar to an App2 which also has defined Auxiliar data class but I get the following error:

`E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.opp.App1.ui.main.Auxiliar`

I think that App2 is trying to find Auxiliar definition when retrieving bundle info and I don't know how to say to use Auxiliar defined in App2

Here is some code

```
@Parcelize
data class Auxiliar(
    var nightId: Long = 0L,

    val startTimeMilli: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),

    var endTimeMilli: Long = startTimeMilli,

    var quality: Int = -1
): Parcelable
```

App1

```
var intent: Intent? = activity?.packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.opp.App2")

val argu1 = Auxiliar(-101, 1,1,-1)
if (intent != null) {
            var bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable("una", argu1)
            intent.putExtra("myBundle",bundle)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
}
```

Retrieve in App2:

```
val bundle = activity?.intent?.getBundleExtra("myBundle")
if (bundle != null) {
    var una = bundle.getParcelable<Auxiliar>("una")
    }
```

Comment: "I don't know how to say to use Auxiliar defined in App2" -- you can't. They need to be the same class: same definition, same fully-qualified class name.

Comment: So... You cannot pass parcelable class from one app to another? You can only pass primitive classes?

Comment: Well if you have the same class by the same fully qualified package name then it'd work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You cannot pass parcelable class from one app to another?

Yes, you can. However, they have to be **the same class**. In other words, they need to have:

- The same base name (`Auxiliar`)
- The same package name (`com.opp.App1.ui.main`)
- The same fields

In your case, I am guessing that the package name is different. If you use the same package name in both apps — such as having both apps share a common library module that defines the class — then you will be in somewhat better shape.

However, bear in mind that users do not need to update App1 and App2 at the same time. `Parcelable` is designed for use by framework classes, ones that are part of the firmware, where App1 and App2 are guaranteed to have the same implementation. If App1 has an old `Auxiliar` and App2 has a new `Auxiliar`, you may run into problems.

> You can only pass primitive classes?

Passing anything that is defined in the Android SDK as `Parcelable` is safe, because App1 and App2 will have the same class definition for those classes. So, for example, `Bundle` is `Parcelable`. You would still need a versioning system to deal with data changes, but at least you are in control over how to handle that.